# Problems with fast reading a binary file with numbers c++

Tags: c++, performance, binary

i know these topic exist very often. But i cant explain my self the slow results i have.

My Task: read from a file 2.2M Points per sec (better more) and show them in a 3d OpenCv Window.

I try to read on different ways:

- Cartesian coordinated system (x,y,z) all __int16 650.000 Points per second
- spherical coordinates system (phi, theta, distance) all __int16 560.000  Points per second
- spherical coordinates system (distance) __int16 1.384.000  Points per second and calculate phi and theta from sequence (this is maybe possible in far future, but now i havent points with equal angle distance)

I have an SSD and run in release mode.
So i thought it cant be a bottle neck problem.

it is a binary file and i use float. System is 32bit and i will get 2Byte values.

what is my mistake? pls give me an advice.
My code for reading  spherical coordinates system (phi, theta, distance)

Global

```
 Point *pvertex=nullptr;
 pvertex=new Point[pointsToShow];
```

readPoints()

```
RealTime=clock();
std::ifstream FFile;
FFile.open ("read.txt",std::ifstream::in|std::ifstream::binary);

while (FFile!=NULL)
{
    FFile.read((char *)&fphi,sizeof(float));
    FFile.read((char *)&ftheta,sizeof(float));
    FFile.read((char *)&fdistance,sizeof(float));

    pvertex[position].x = fdistance* sin(ftheta)*cos(fphi);
    pvertex[position].z = fdistance* sin(ftheta)*sin(fphi);
    pvertex[position].y = fdistance* cos(ftheta);
    position++;
}

clock_t ende=clock();
if(ende-RealTime>0)
    printf("%lld\n", (long long)(ende-RealTime+(pointsToShow/(ende-RealTime))*1000));
```

Comment: ***System::Console::WriteLine*** That is should be `c++-cli` although the reading code is `c++`. I would remove the `opengl` tag since this has little to do with that.

Comment: ***what is my mistake?*** Maybe you should tell us. It's unclear what problem you are experiencing. Is the reading of the file too slow? Or is the data corrupted? ***i will get 2Byte values*** floats are not 2 bytes. Not sure if you thought that.

Comment: Have you tried reading more data at once ? I would assume the overhead of calling read multiple times might slow things down.

Comment: ***pls give me an advice.*** If performance is your problem my advice is to benchmark. Does your reading code read fast enough without the drawing to the screen. If not maybe you need to read more values at a time. You may want to also try the file reading in native `c++` to see if that helps any.

Comment: Since this is fundamentally a C++ question, I re-wrote the `Console::WriteLine` to a `printf`, and switched back to the C++ tag.

Comment: Thx for correct the tags. It reads to slow. 2.2mP are round 25MB. Reading vom SSD should be faster. It isnt faster without drawing. Ok i will try reading more values on one time.

Comment: now i read all points at once and use memcpy. Now i can read 7MP per second. Thats enough. Thx for help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `read()` and `fstream`, you could create a memory mapping over the file (`mmap` on Linux, `CreateFileMapping` on Windows).

This way you can access the data as if it were in memory (directly from the OS disk cache), instead of reading and copying smaller blocks to a user mode buffer.